# How to provide dependency injections in Eclipse RCP 3.x?

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, rcp

everyone!

I'm trying to deal with Eclipse RCP 3.x application. 
I've read a lot of articles about dependency injection in RCP e4 applications. 
Can we use DI in RCP 3.x apps?

I found perfect [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ContextUsage/article.html#extending-the-objects-available-for-the-dependency-injection) about DI in e4. Any idea how could I use it in RCP 3.x app?

First of all, I'm interested in my own objects injection (BTW, how could I add my own object to the application context?).

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

In the 3.x code you can get the `IEclipseContext` necessary to use `ContextInjectionFactory` using

```java
IEclipseContext workbenchContext = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEclipseContext.class);
```

to get the workbench context.

In a view or editor you can get the current part context using:

```java
IEclipseContext partContext = getSite().getService(IEclipseContext.class);
```

Comment: Hi, @Greg! 
I'm trying to inject my own service. As I understand, I should add my service to the IEclipseContext.
I tried this:
`IEclipseContext context = (IEclipseContext) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEclipseContext.class);
        context.set(PersonService.class, new PersonService());`
After that, I marked the field with @Inject annotation this way:
`    @Inject
    private PersonService service;`

But injection isn't works (service is always null by default).
So that I have a  question:
Where in the app I should add my service to the context?

Comment: `@Inject` will only work in classes created using ContextInjectionFactory. The Eclipse 3.x code does not use that for views, editors or other classes (this will change in Eclipse 4.7) So you can only really use DI in classes you create yourself with ContextInjectionFactory.

Comment: Thank you, @Greg! 
I tried something like this
`IEclipseContext context = (IEclipseContext) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEclipseContext.class);
        context.set(PersonService.class, new PersonService());
PersonService service = context.get(PersonService.class);`
and it works